# Node Express Handlebars variable issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'd like to add a variable where [10] is. Like articles.[id].[#comments].

```
{{#each articles.[10].[#comments]}}
  <h1>{{subject}}</h1>
  <div>
    {{body}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: please include express code as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{{#each articles.10.[#comments]}}
  <h1>{{subject}}</h1>
  <div>
    {{body}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: How is this any different from what he wrote?

Comment: Thank you, but I need to replace 10 with a variable, like row_id. For example: articles.row_id.[#comments]